# Is the rule that "Lists with three items sound better" specific to English?

Tags: english

For example, the sentence "Todd liked crunchy apples, brown bananas, and small oranges" sounds better than "Todd liked crunchy apples and brown bananas".

Generally, if you're listing off things, three items (at least when compared with only two items) sounds "correct" or "more complete" in a sort of rhythmic or aesthetic sense. What might be a reason for this? Is it specific to English? As a native English speaker it seems almost like an unwritten rule of the language.

This question was inspired by a bit from the sitcom *30 Rock*.

Comment: It's called the ["Rule of Three"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(writing)), and has a long history in many languages. Also the [Hendiatris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendiatris) dates back to the classical era.